# Android ImageButtons with Pressed State Not Showing

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm facing an issue with my Android app involving ImageButtons. I have implemented selectors for the pressed state of the buttons, but the pressed state effect is not being displayed when the buttons are clicked or focused.

Problem:
I have defined selectors (**consumption_selector.xml**, **shopping_selector.xml**, **inventory_selector.xml**) for the **ImageButton** backgrounds to display a different image when pressed or focused. However, despite setting up the selectors correctly, the pressed state effect is not being shown when interacting with the buttons.

What I've Tried:
I've ensured that the selector files are correctly defined and placed in the **res/drawable** directory.
Each **ImageButton** has its background set to the corresponding selector.
I've verified that the **onClick** event is triggered by adding a **Toast** on button clicks, and it's working fine.

consumption_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/consumption2" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/consumption2" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/consumption" />
</selector>
```

shopping_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buying2" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buying2" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buying" />
</selector>
```

inventory_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inventory2" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inventory2" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inventory" />
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:src="@drawable/consumo"
    android:background="@drawable/consumo_selector"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_consumo"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:src="@drawable/compras"
    android:background="@drawable/compras_selector"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_compras"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ImageButton01"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:src="@drawable/estoque"
    android:background="@drawable/estoque_selector"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_estoque"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ImageButton02"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.project.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Botão 1 clicado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `android:src` drawable same with the default state drawable of the selector?
If it is, you can just remove src drawable. Then you can see the selector correctly.